Mellanox ConnectX-3 very high cpu usage
I bought MCX311A-XCAT CX311A ConnectX-3 for my dev server with the idea to buy another one if this works for my pc. Currently my storage server and my pc have 2.5Gbe.  They are all plugged into unmanaged switch Davuaz Da-K6402W. Dev server is Xeon E-2136 up to 4.5GHz. Storage and dev servers use Rocky Linux 9 (RHEL-based) - kernel 5.14.0. The 10G NIC works, but the cpu usage is about 70% (that's 70% on one core) with iperf3 connection to storage server at about 2.30 Gbits/sec. Storage server on the other hand is Xeon E3-1285L - much older and it iperf3 uses 5 to 10% cpu there.
When copying from a machine with 1G NIC it uses 30% cpu.
That also adds up as power consumption. I measured the power of my storage server with this nic. it goes from 66W to 105W (+40W) because of cpu usage just communicating at 2.5Gbit/s. limiting the cpu to 1GHz reduced the power to 70W (just 4 more watts than idle).
CPU package power: 38-40W for the Xeon E-2136 with 10G NIC which idles at 1W
CPU package power: 19W for E3-1285L with 2.5G NIC which idles at 10W
Just figured out that sending at 2.5G/s keeps the CPU at 5%, receiving -68% (all other tests are bi-directional.
Why does the 10G NIC need that much CPU even at low speeds? Any recommendations for cheaper homelab options for 10G SPF+ NICs which .
Note: the eth device is in a bridge - br0. However I tested without bridge - no change.
Update: Tried ubuntu 24 LTS, kernel 6.8 - same story. receive 50-60% cpu, send: 2-3% cpu
Update: Updated firmware but still no change:
mstflint -d 02:00.0 q
Image type:            FS2
FW Version:            2.42.5000
FW Release Date:       5.9.2017
Product Version:       02.42.50.00
Rom Info:              type=PXE version=3.4.752
Device ID:             4099
Description:           Node             Port1            Port2            Sys image
GUIDs:                 ffffffffffffffff ffffffffffffffff ffffffffffffffff ffffffffffffffff
MACs:                                       248a07bac7d0     248a07bac7d1
VSD:
PSID:                  MT_1170110023

more info:
ethtool -k eth2
Features for eth2:
rx-checksumming: on
tx-checksumming: on
        tx-checksum-ipv4: on
        tx-checksum-ip-generic: off [fixed]
        tx-checksum-ipv6: on
        tx-checksum-fcoe-crc: off [fixed]
        tx-checksum-sctp: off [fixed]
scatter-gather: on
        tx-scatter-gather: on
        tx-scatter-gather-fraglist: off [fixed]
tcp-segmentation-offload: on
        tx-tcp-segmentation: on
        tx-tcp-ecn-segmentation: off [fixed]
        tx-tcp-mangleid-segmentation: off
        tx-tcp6-segmentation: on
generic-segmentation-offload: on
generic-receive-offload: on
large-receive-offload: off [fixed]
rx-vlan-offload: on
tx-vlan-offload: on
ntuple-filters: off [fixed]
receive-hashing: on
highdma: on [fixed]
rx-vlan-filter: on [fixed]
vlan-challenged: off [fixed]
tx-lockless: off [fixed]
netns-local: off [fixed]
tx-gso-robust: off [fixed]
tx-fcoe-segmentation: off [fixed]
tx-gre-segmentation: off [fixed]
tx-gre-csum-segmentation: off [fixed]
tx-ipxip4-segmentation: off [fixed]
tx-ipxip6-segmentation: off [fixed]
tx-udp_tnl-segmentation: off [fixed]
tx-udp_tnl-csum-segmentation: off [fixed]
tx-gso-partial: off [fixed]
tx-tunnel-remcsum-segmentation: off [fixed]
tx-sctp-segmentation: off [fixed]
tx-esp-segmentation: off [fixed]
tx-udp-segmentation: off [fixed]
tx-gso-list: off [fixed]
fcoe-mtu: off [fixed]
tx-nocache-copy: off
loopback: off
rx-fcs: off
rx-all: off
tx-vlan-stag-hw-insert: off
rx-vlan-stag-hw-parse: on
rx-vlan-stag-filter: on [fixed]
l2-fwd-offload: off [fixed]
hw-tc-offload: off [fixed]
esp-hw-offload: off [fixed]
esp-tx-csum-hw-offload: off [fixed]
rx-udp_tunnel-port-offload: off [fixed]
tls-hw-tx-offload: off [fixed]
tls-hw-rx-offload: off [fixed]
rx-gro-hw: off [fixed]
tls-hw-record: off [fixed]
rx-gro-list: off
macsec-hw-offload: off [fixed]
rx-udp-gro-forwarding: off
hsr-tag-ins-offload: off [fixed]
hsr-tag-rm-offload: off [fixed]
hsr-fwd-offload: off [fixed]
hsr-dup-offload: off [fixed]

## was 1024, I set it to 8192 - no change
# ethtool -g eth2
Ring parameters for eth2:
Pre-set maximums:
RX:             8192
RX Mini:        n/a
RX Jumbo:       n/a
TX:             8192
Current hardware settings:
RX:             8192
RX Mini:        n/a
RX Jumbo:       n/a
TX:             8192
RX Buf Len:     n/a
CQE Size:       n/a
TX Push:        off
TCP data split: n/a

# ethtool -S eth2
NIC statistics:
     rx_packets: 273
     tx_packets: 232
     rx_bytes: 53328
     tx_bytes: 36010
     rx_errors: 0
     tx_errors: 0
     rx_dropped: 0
     tx_dropped: 0
     multicast: 21
     collisions: 0
     rx_length_errors: 0
     rx_over_errors: 0
     rx_crc_errors: 0
     rx_frame_errors: 0
     rx_fifo_errors: 0
     rx_missed_errors: 0
     tx_aborted_errors: 0
     tx_carrier_errors: 0
     tx_fifo_errors: 0
     tx_heartbeat_errors: 0
     tx_window_errors: 0
     tso_packets: 0
     xmit_more: 0
     queue_stopped: 0
     wake_queue: 0
     tx_timeout: 0
     rx_alloc_pages: 65536
     rx_csum_good: 261
     rx_csum_none: 11
     rx_csum_complete: 0
     tx_chksum_offload: 222
     rx_pause: 0
     rx_pause_duration: 0
     rx_pause_transition: 0
     tx_pause: 0
     tx_pause_duration: 0
     tx_pause_transition: 0
     rx_multicast_packets: 21
     rx_broadcast_packets: 14
     rx_jabbers: 0
     rx_in_range_length_error: 0
     rx_out_range_length_error: 0
     tx_multicast_packets: 24
     tx_broadcast_packets: 0
     rx_prio_0_packets: 0
     rx_prio_0_bytes: 0
     rx_prio_1_packets: 0
     rx_prio_1_bytes: 0
     rx_prio_2_packets: 0
     rx_prio_2_bytes: 0
     rx_prio_3_packets: 0
     rx_prio_3_bytes: 0
     rx_prio_4_packets: 0
     rx_prio_4_bytes: 0
     rx_prio_5_packets: 0
     rx_prio_5_bytes: 0
     rx_prio_6_packets: 0
     rx_prio_6_bytes: 0
     rx_prio_7_packets: 0
     rx_prio_7_bytes: 0
     rx_novlan_packets: 272
     rx_novlan_bytes: 54298
     tx_prio_0_packets: 0
     tx_prio_0_bytes: 0
     tx_prio_1_packets: 0
     tx_prio_1_bytes: 0
     tx_prio_2_packets: 0
     tx_prio_2_bytes: 0
     tx_prio_3_packets: 0
     tx_prio_3_bytes: 0
     tx_prio_4_packets: 0
     tx_prio_4_bytes: 0
     tx_prio_5_packets: 0
     tx_prio_5_bytes: 0
     tx_prio_6_packets: 0
     tx_prio_6_bytes: 0
     tx_prio_7_packets: 0
     tx_prio_7_bytes: 0
     tx_novlan_packets: 231
     tx_novlan_bytes: 36816
     rx_xdp_drop: 0
     rx_xdp_redirect: 0
     rx_xdp_redirect_fail: 0
     rx_xdp_tx: 0
     rx_xdp_tx_full: 0
     rx_packets_phy: 272
     rx_bytes_phy: 54298
     tx_packets_phy: 231
     tx_bytes_phy: 36816
     tx0_packets: 0
     tx0_bytes: 0
     tx1_packets: 21
     tx1_bytes: 2529
     tx2_packets: 29
     tx2_bytes: 3887
     tx3_packets: 13
     tx3_bytes: 1103
     tx4_packets: 4
     tx4_bytes: 532
     tx5_packets: 24
     tx5_bytes: 2806
     tx6_packets: 10
     tx6_bytes: 855
     tx7_packets: 15
     tx7_bytes: 4787
     tx8_packets: 6
     tx8_bytes: 599
     tx9_packets: 48
     tx9_bytes: 7392
     tx10_packets: 52
     tx10_bytes: 8432
     tx11_packets: 10
     tx11_bytes: 3088
     rx0_packets: 75
     rx0_bytes: 7448
     rx0_dropped: 0
     rx0_xdp_drop: 0
     rx0_xdp_redirect: 0
     rx0_xdp_redirect_fail: 0
     rx0_xdp_tx: 0
     rx0_xdp_tx_full: 0
     rx1_packets: 25
     rx1_bytes: 3573
     rx1_dropped: 0
     rx1_xdp_drop: 0
     rx1_xdp_redirect: 0
     rx1_xdp_redirect_fail: 0
     rx1_xdp_tx: 0
     rx1_xdp_tx_full: 0
     rx2_packets: 10
     rx2_bytes: 2236
     rx2_dropped: 0
     rx2_xdp_drop: 0
     rx2_xdp_redirect: 0
     rx2_xdp_redirect_fail: 0
     rx2_xdp_tx: 0
     rx2_xdp_tx_full: 0
     rx3_packets: 29
     rx3_bytes: 8095
     rx3_dropped: 0
     rx3_xdp_drop: 0
     rx3_xdp_redirect: 0
     rx3_xdp_redirect_fail: 0
     rx3_xdp_tx: 0
     rx3_xdp_tx_full: 0
     rx4_packets: 38
     rx4_bytes: 12986
     rx4_dropped: 0
     rx4_xdp_drop: 0
     rx4_xdp_redirect: 0
     rx4_xdp_redirect_fail: 0
     rx4_xdp_tx: 0
     rx4_xdp_tx_full: 0
     rx5_packets: 20
     rx5_bytes: 4753
     rx5_dropped: 0
     rx5_xdp_drop: 0
     rx5_xdp_redirect: 0
     rx5_xdp_redirect_fail: 0
     rx5_xdp_tx: 0
     rx5_xdp_tx_full: 0
     rx6_packets: 41
     rx6_bytes: 4314
     rx6_dropped: 0
     rx6_xdp_drop: 0
     rx6_xdp_redirect: 0
     rx6_xdp_redirect_fail: 0
     rx6_xdp_tx: 0
     rx6_xdp_tx_full: 0
     rx7_packets: 35
     rx7_bytes: 9923
     rx7_dropped: 0
     rx7_xdp_drop: 0
     rx7_xdp_redirect: 0
     rx7_xdp_redirect_fail: 0
     rx7_xdp_tx: 0
     rx7_xdp_tx_full: 0


Read the RHEL chapter on tuning network performance  https://docs.redhat.com/en/documentation/red_hat_enterprise_linux/9/html/monitoring_and_managing_system_status_and_performance/tuning-the-network-performance_monitoring-and-managing-system-status-and-performance   and edit your question with what you learned about your network adapter.   In particular:  how it spreads across CPUs in /proc/interrupts  and /proc/softirqs   and the various offload and coalescence  features  reported by ethtool

I will do that soon. Thanks! For now I posted ethtool -k

dev/lab question are offtopic, but I would suspect a driver issue, did you checked with modprobe mlx4_en, as the offloading seem to hit your server cpu, not the adapter's one.

@yagmoth555 tried ubuntu with kernel 6.8 - same problem. newer kernel, more fixes right (well redhat kinda backport things so you never know). But why only receive... strange
